# Is there a more efficient way to center an image inside a floated div

Tags: html, css, css-float, centering

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to center an image inside a floated div compared to mine. Right now I have it set up so the image is placed inside a p and I center the p. Seeing that extra p tag annoys me way too much :(. Is there anyway I can center the img by itself? Thanks! I listed what I have now down below. Edit: It needs to be vertical and horizontal!

HTML

```
<div class="filler"><p><img src="images/qualGraphic.png" width="578px" height="256.72px" alt="Quality"/></p></div>
```

CSS

```
.filler {
    display:table;
    width:65.6%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#000;
    display: table;
    float:left;
}
.filler p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: how about adding style="position:relative;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" to the <img>
I'm not sure why .filler is display:table.

Comment: Are you trying to center vertically, horizontally or both?

Comment: vertical and horizontal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center both horizontally and vertically try adding this to the image.

```
img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

The element around the image needs to be positioned relatively i.e.

```
position: relative
```

Here's an example with an image inside a floated element

http://jsfiddle.net/xYEuS/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CSS property `text-align:center` to the `.filler` class. An `img` is an inline element so it will center according the the `text-align` property.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/CgJZ4/

Comment: I need it vertical and horizontal. Thanks for the help!