# Is this the most efficient way of dead centering a div?

Tags: css, centering

```
#outer {
    display:table;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#middle {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#inner {
    margin:50px auto 50px auto;
    width:600px;
}

<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="inner">
                dead centered onto screen
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is this the most efficient, or accepted, way of dead centering a div in the middle of the screen? I ask because using tables for anything but tabular data, especially for architecting an interface, is so frowned upon.

Comment: what is dead centering and how does it differ from normal centering?

Comment: Same thing Aziz because English.

Comment: Opinion based and so off-topic. Anyway, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339958/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-center-an-image-inside-a-floated-div?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS transforms or flexbox.

**Option 1: CSS (2D) transforms.** [Global support: 90.8%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). The trick is to position the element 50% from the top and left, and offset by its own dimensions, by half, in the opposite direction. The only drawback of this method is that it might lead to fuzzy text rendering because of subpixel translations.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper > .content {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">Centered</div>
</div>
```

**Option 2: CSS flexbox.** [Complete global support: 82.81%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). Browser support a little patchier compared to CSS transforms, but involves less lines. The trick is to set both `align-items` and `justify-content` to center on the parent element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper > .content {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">Centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Option 1 is an interesting one. If option 1 only has 91% global support, would not my original option have a higher one? What browser doesn't support tables?

Comment: @The_Machine All browser support tables(or table based layout), but noticed that you need three levels of beating. My solution only requires two. Divitis is dangerous ;)

Comment: Isn't 3 better than 2? =D

Comment: @The_Machine Oh god I meant "nesting". Autocorrect!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is second way.... try: `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`

Comment: Dat vertical alignment doe.